# Trial Expired -Can it be extended?

Tags: google-contacts-api

My trial version of 'Natural Language RM' from Google Developer APIs has expired, but I'm still trying to get this startup (Nelpy) off the ground.  Can I get an extension or do you have another program more cost effective?

Answer (score 0):

No you can not extend the trial but you can have alternative of it .
best alternative are TOMTOM and MapBox